# Does Interrail check for proof of residence and if so in which countries?

Tags: residency, interrail

I'm going on a trip with Interrail soon. My friends (from the UK) don't actually have an official proof of residence and are a bit worried.

Is anyone actually checked for their proof of residence and if so in which countries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When they have an UK passport, that will be enough for the 'residence' requirement.

Officially you can only buy an InterRail pass in the country you live, but if they are from one of the countries where the residents/citizens can buy an InterRail pass, they should bring their passport or ID card and if possible something that proofs that they live in the UK. Most railway stations are not that bothered to check where you live, but some staff member might be.

When buying online they do not check it at the time you buy and as such they should carry official proof:

> What can be used as proof of residence?
>   Your residence can be proved using official government-issued residency papers. This must be a document that clearly shows that you are a resident of the country you live in (e.g. a residence card). Documents such as bills, rental contracts or bank statements cannot be used. Working visas and/or travel visas can also not be used as proof of residency. The residency field of a passport can also not be used as proof of residence.

That and more can be found in the [FAQ of the InterRail site](http://www.interrail.eu/help/ordering-pass/do-i-need-interrail-or-eurail-pass).

I have traveled several times with InterRail, my passport has been checked against the information on the pass. As I have a Dutch, so EU/participant country, passport, that was that. I have heard that in some countries they check the pass and passport every time, in others at odd intervals. But I have not heard that in any country they did not check it at all.

Comment: It is similar with BritRail passes: they send the pass to the faraway country where you live, and you show your passport when you activate the pass. A passport isn't proof of residency, but they don't seem to mind. Perhaps if you were constantly buying them, they might want more proof after a while.

Comment: InterRail is available for citizens of the participant countries as well as for people who have been resident for 6 months in those countries, as well as for citizens (and maybe residents) of some more selected countries. Britrail is available for all tourists to the UK, so completely different rules.

Comment: Great thanks! I was worried that the passport wouldn't be ok since the terms and conditions state that, but if this is the case it should be fine.